# Windows Media Player Device Sync in VB.NET using WMPLIB

Tags: c++, vb.net, device, synchronization, windows-media-player

The MSDN documentation for WMPLIB states that syncing to device is not supported in .NET programming, only C++.

Is there, however, a simple wrapper class or DLL that can be used to interface between a .NET program and the nescessary C++ code?

Or is there a better way to sync files to a device using VB.NET? Are all devices suited/compatible with just a simple filesystem.copyfile ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing wrapper. Maybe others can help out with that.

Have you tried C++/CLI? You can write a simple C++/CLI project that can interop with C/C++, but its functions are visible from other .NET languages, just like C# or VB.NET. We've had a lot of success wrapping C++ code using C++/CLI, I recommend it.

Comment: I've considered it, but I have never used C++. I'll go down this route if there are no alternatives...